# Custom C# Button Does Nothing When Clicked Any Ideas?

Tags: c#, button

I have just made a new button for my C# uni project. For some reason it doesn't seem to work any ideas?

Here is my code for the button:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSD_A2_WS2435593_WS243380.Classes.FormsaAndControls
{
    class clsFlatButton : Button //control object declaration.
    {
        public clsFlatButton()
        {
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 236, 244);
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(57, 115, 157);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e) //draws the rectangle and text
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, new Point(Width + 3, Height / 2), ForeColor, flags);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e) //changes on mouse hover it enters the box
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            BackColor = onMouseHoverBackColour;
            ForeColor = onMouseHoverForeColour;
        }
        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) //changes on mouse hover when it leaves the box
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 236, 244);
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(57, 115, 157);
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) //changes on mouse click
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(57, 115, 157);
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 236, 244);
        }
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 236, 244);
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(57, 115, 157);
        }
        //Available settings:
        //Static values for initialisation.
        private Color onMouseHoverBackColour = Color.FromArgb(251, 255, 255);
        private Color onMouseHoverForeColour = Color.FromArgb(6, 64, 106);
        //These will appear on the clsFlatButton control so they can be changed.
        public Color onMouseHoverBackColourChanger
        {
            get { return onMouseHoverBackColour;}
            set { onMouseHoverBackColour = value; }
        }
        public Color onMouseHoverForeColourChanger
        {
            get { return onMouseHoverForeColour; }
            set { onMouseHoverForeColour = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I go to click it it does change colour even when hover, though it does not actually execute the code inside of it.

So I have nothing else to say but stackoverflow won't let me post this question without more normal text. So here we go I guess, I could just paste lorem ipsum but I don't want to be shouted at.

EDIT: #1 Image as requested:
[Screenshot of button properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDGt4.png)

Comment: Ok why do you say it does not work? are you getting an error? can you show where this button is declared.   Have you placed break points inside OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp.... do they get executed?  I am not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: What code does not get exectuted? Also I dont see event handlers for click... I see for mousedown and mouseup which is not the same.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Okay, yeah I have tried breakpoints but they don't do much, everything gets executed pretty much, Here is the declaration on my login form: private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("BigOOF");
        }

Comment: Hold on a minute... do you mean that I have to declare a handler inside the button that is a inherited from "Button" so it actually works like a button?

Comment: I meant in your overrides.... What I want to know is what code that does NOT get executed? I am confused what is the problem....

Comment: OK... I see... this is the Event Handler for Click:   "private void BtnLogin_Click".... You are saying that "MessageBox.Show("BigOOF");" never shows a MessageBox?

Comment: Okay, so I use that button on my login form that should get me to log in, I ran a test with the messagebox that I commented above^^^ it doesn't show the messagebox at all.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Yes boss

Comment: Ok how did you register the event handler to the button? can you post a picture of the button properties in the designer showing the even associated to it?  or can you show the code that programmatically registers the event handler to the click event?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I got the image added.

Comment: I found the problem but someone beat me to the answer.... hahaha

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Lol. Such a simple error. Upvoting your effort here.

Comment: Both of you are awesome, thank you so much! Been staring at this crap for a while. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are invoking

`base.OnMouseDown` and not `base.OnMouseUp` in

```
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
```

I've reproduced the problem, and fixed it by:

```
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 236, 244);
        ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(57, 115, 157);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, legend. You guys came through yet again. Love you!
P.S.: I am intellectually challenged.

Comment: No legend at all. Just a debugging paranoid :)

Comment: I love being here too, be safe.